# динамическое использование DataGridComboBoxColumn для редактирования TextBox-ячеек DataGrid'a

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Как правильно сделать чтобы содержимое колонки DataGrid (которое отображается как TextBox) редактировалось по принципу ComboBox'a?

**Предистория**: приложение обрабатывает данные из нескольких почти идентичных таблиц, для этого создано **одно** базовое окно показа/обработки, которое использует DataGrid c автоматическим созданием столбцов. В разметке (xaml) определены лишь некоторые мелочи для внешнего вида и пара конвертеров цвета фона и шрифта. На главном окне приложения есть несколько кнопок, которые открывают окно обработки, переопределяя источник данных. 
Всё всех устраивало - при щелчке по ячейке она переходило в режим редактирования, потом отлавливалось событие завершения и так далее.

**Теперь** для одной таблицы понадобилось в одном поле выбирать данные из статического списка (напрашивается использование ComboBox'a), но не хочется отказываться от автогенерации столбцов - не использую разметку, хочется программно. Поэтому от базового класса окна обработки наследую новый класс (он и будет новым окном), отлавливаю myGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn и в нём и хочу переделать искомый столбец (распознаю по названию) в DataGridComboBoxColumn, чтоб при редактировании открывался списком.

Под "рукой" только искомый **column**, могу менять его свойства, но переопределить стиль его представления не получается. Блэкаут. Или я пытаюсь не в том месте ?

Comment: у вас есть возможность написать `MCVE`? Не совсем понятно в чем именно проблема, так как тот способ, который вы описываете звучит логично.

Comment: создать ComboBox получилось,  сложнее оказалось установить в нём пришедшие из базы значения.  Поэтому отказался от этого способа.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант не изменять стиль колонки а удалять и создавать новую:

```
public class ModelDG : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var e = PropertyChanged;
            if (e != null)
            {
                e(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ListName { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<ModelDG> ListDG = new ObservableCollection<ModelDG>() 
        {
             new ModelDG{ Name ="String1", ListName="ComboBox1"},
             new ModelDG{ Name ="String2", ListName="ComboBox2"},
             new ModelDG{ Name ="String3", ListName="ComboBox3"},
             new ModelDG{ Name ="String4", ListName="ComboBox4"},
             new ModelDG{ Name ="String5", ListName="ComboBox5"},
             new ModelDG{ Name ="String6", ListName="ComboBox6"},
        };

        dgrid.ItemsSource = ListDG;
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(DataGridColumn col in dgrid.Columns)
        {

            if (col.DisplayIndex == 1)
            {
                DataGridComboBoxColumn columnCB = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                columnCB.ItemsSource = new List<string>
                {
                    "One","Two","Tree","Four"
                };
                columnCB.Header = "ListNames";

                dgrid.Columns.Add(columnCB);
                dgrid.Columns.Remove(col);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. Думаю что результат один и тот-же (находясь в "DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" я просто распознаю мой столбец и заменяю его новым ComboBox'ом так : args.Column = myDGCBC). Проблема в том, что я теряю значение, которое изначально приходит из базы! Т.е. новый ComboBox присутствует, но значение в нём не выбрано. Как быть ?

Comment: Надо хранить то что пришло из базы, а не выбрасывать. А лучше применить подход MVVM

Answer (score 0):

потратив кучу времени я отказался от автогенерации колонок и сделал разметку вручную:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mapping" Width="110">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mapping}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Height="22" ItemsSource="{StaticResource MappingList}"
                                              SelectedValue="{Binding Mapping}"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Теперь при редактировании появляется ComboBox, потом всё выглядит как обычное текстовое поле. 
Но возникла связанная проблема - как проверить выбранное (т.н. новое) в ComboBox'e значение ? Использую событие **DataGrid_CellEditEnding**, но добраться до ComboBox'a не получается!!! Как параметр получаю     **DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e**, но радости от этого мало - вижу только неизменённые данные...

Comment: У вас же вроде есть привязка SelectedValue к кому-то свойству, почему бы не отслеживать его изменение?

Comment: не совсем понял ответ - отслеживать изменение чего ? Если поля "Mapping", то о нём и речь - не могу достучаться до выбранного нового значания, находясь в  DataGrid_CellEditEnding. Если есть другая возможность - благодарен за любые идеи.

Comment: Ну смотрите, SelectedValue="{Binding Mapping}" означает, что свойство Mapping всегда будет имеет значение свойства SelectedValue и наоборот, правильно? Т.е., если вы не можете получить объект, содержащий свойство Mapping из обработчика  DataGrid_CellEditEnding, то вы можете попробовать реализовать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged для типа, который содержит Mapping